# Subtract two values in Kibana for specific timestamps

Tags: elastic-stack, kibana-5

This is the first time Im doing this and cant seem to find an online resource.

The index is aggregated at a daily level. So one record per day.

**26 April:**

```
    {
  "_index": "gamers",
  "_type": "dailyAgg",
  "_id": "dailyAgg-2015-04-26T00:00:00Z",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "timestamp": "2017-04-26T00:00:00Z",
    "player_count": 800
  },
    "timestamp": [
      1493164800000
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1493164800000
  ]
}
```

**25 April:**

```
{
  "_index": "gamers",
  "_type": "dailyAgg",
  "_id": "dailyAgg-2017-04-25T00:00:00Z",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "timestamp": "2017-04-25T00:00:00Z",
    "player_count": 500
  },
    "timestamp": [
      1493078400000
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1493078400000
  ]
}
```

What I need is:

> player_count(Today) - player_count(Yesterday)
>
> => player_count(26 April) - player_count(25 April) = 800 - 500 = 300

I've tried scripted field and painless scripts, but cant pull the data for the given date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I ended up using: [Custom Plugin](https://github.com/ommsolutions/kibana_ext_metrics_vis)